# add text before all other text in element

Tags: jquery

How would i go about adding text to all my current captions

```
<caption><span>Existing Caption Text</span></caption>
<caption><span>Existing Caption Text2</span></caption>
<caption><span>Existing Caption Text3</span></caption>
<caption><span>Existing Caption Text4</span></caption>
```

So i want to add text to each caption and have it shown first in the order

result would be

```
<caption><span>NEW TEXT Existing Caption Text</span></caption>
<caption><span>NEW TEXT Existing Caption Text2</span></caption>
<caption><span>NEW TEXT Existing Caption Text3</span></caption>
<caption><span>NEW TEXT Existing Caption Text4</span></caption>
```

i know how to replace the text using , but i just want it added to the existing.

```
$('caption span').text('NEW TEXT');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide the `text()` method with a function can be used to amend the existing text value of the element. Try this:

```
$('caption span').text(function(i, text) {
    return 'NEW TEXT ' + text;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

YOu can do it using **.each** in jquery

```
$('caption span').each(function() {
    $(this).html('NEW TEXT ' +$(this).html());
});
```

This should work...

Answer (score 0):

You can even use this:

```
$('caption span').html(function(i, text) {
    return 'NEW TEXT ' + text;
});
```